# Error: the following arguments are required

Tags: command-line-arguments, face-detection, eye-detection

This is my code:

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-p", "--shape-predictor", required=True,
    help="path to facial landmark predictor", default="shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")
ap.add_argument("-a", "--alarm", type=str, default="alaram.wav",
    help="path alarm .WAV file")
ap.add_argument("-w", "--webcam", type=int, default=0,
    help="index of webcam on system")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

this is my code

[image: X]

usage:

```
detect_drowsiness.py [-h] -p SHAPE_PREDICTOR [-a ALARM] [-w WEBCAM]
```

I am geting an error:

> detect_drowsiness.py: error: the following arguments are required:
>   -p/--shape-predict

Answer (score 1):

Download the file `shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat` from here http://dlib.net/files/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2 and extract it and place in project directory and execute your python file with `detect_drowsiness.py -p shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.`

That needed file is a trained model for Dlib!